# Installing Java from console

Tags: software-installation, java, jdk, openjdk

I have tried to install Java using the following instruction:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

But after sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java I get ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module>
from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'softwareproperties'
```

I have checked "ls -l /usr/bin/python*":

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        9 гру 21 12:16 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        9 гру 21 12:16 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3546104 лис 19 11:35 /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       33 лис 19 11:35 /usr/bin/python2.7-config ->    x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       16 гру 10  2015 /usr/bin/python2-config -> python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        9 січ  8 20:31 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4460336 лис 17 21:23 /usr/bin/python3.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       33 лис 17 21:23 /usr/bin/python3.5-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.5-config
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4460336 лис 17 21:23 /usr/bin/python3.5m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       34 лис 17 21:23 /usr/bin/python3.5m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.5m-config
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 12504344 січ  8 20:31 /usr/bin/python3.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       17 січ  8 20:31 /usr/bin/python3.6-config -> python3.6m-config
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 12504344 січ  8 20:31 /usr/bin/python3.6m
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     3091 січ  8 20:31 /usr/bin/python3.6m-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       16 січ  8 20:31 /usr/bin/python3-config -> python3.6-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       10 гру 21 12:16 /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.5m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       17 бер 23  2016 /usr/bin/python3m-config -> python3.5m-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       16 гру 10  2015 /usr/bin/python-config -> python2.7-config
```

Did anybody have such issue ?

Comment: Have you by any chance installed (or tried to install) something python related?

Comment: Will you edit your question and add the output of: `ls -l /usr/bin/python*`?  Give a nudge in the comments when you have done this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have software-properties installed?

Try:

```
apt-get install -y python-software-properties software-properties-common software-properties-gtk python3-software-properties software-properties-kde
```

Comment: For extra information: `-y` tells `apt-get` to assume yes to all questions

Comment: I have tried and got:

Comment: Results:`
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 java-common
 openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64
 update-notifier-common
 flashplugin-installer
 openjdk-8-jre:amd64
 openjdk-8-jdk-headless:amd64
 openjdk-8-jdk:amd64
 update-notifier
 update-manager
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
 ca-certificates-java
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`